# How does the difference between electron flow and conventional flow NOT make a difference?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, light-emitting-diodes

I keep hearing that it doesn't matter whether we use electron flow or conventional flow for direction of current *for simple circuits* like those taught in introductory electrical circuitry classes. And I keep hearing that it's just a convention that was declared and that it doesn't make a difference. **Fine**. But I ask, **how come?**. More specifically, take a simple circuit involving 2 LEDs (top one is red, bottom one is green) in parallel like the image shown below.

[image: 2 electrical circuits with a single cell and 2 LEDs placed in parallel facing opposite directions.]

Conventional current is depicted but electron flow would be the opposite of this. And I'm thinking in this scenario, *it does* matter what direction we take into account as the opposite effects would occur if we took electron flow.

So overall my question is,

> How come for *simple circuits* we say that either convention doesn't matter on the macroscopic level? What are we implying that doesn't change in either model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you chose the opposite convention for the direction of electric current, the LED (diode) would also change its forward direction accordingly. Nothing at all would change in the result. In this sense, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

The conducting direction of the diode is defined by the convention that the electric current flows from the anode ("+" pole) to the cathode ("-" pole). Hence, in both cases the left picture (red path) defines the path the current takes: If we take the perspective of the electrons the diode conducted in the **inverse** direction.